# Advantages of GitHub over Bitbucket for Git Repositories

Tags: git, version-control, github, dvcs, bitbucket

Now that [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) also supports Git repositories, it seams to me that it is a good alternative to [GitHub](https://github.com/), especially since its free plan includes unlimited private repositories, which is not available on GitHub. Yet, GitHub seams much more popular.

Are there any major reasons to choose GitHub as the hosting site for Git repositories instead of Bitbucket?

(Although I have no problems with making my personal projects publicly available in general, I like the idea of being able to make the switch from public to private or vice versa any time I want. But if there are some good reasons to use GitHub, I would be willing to give up this freedom.)

Comment: If you're looking for contribution and a community, then you can't beat GitHub.

Comment: I use both of them. If you produce public stuff you want others to contribute freely, use GitHub. Also GitHub is just awesome from the feature perspective. Otherwise Bitbucket is really nice too and especially useful for private repositories.

Comment: You can search code and wikis on GitHub but not on Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/2874/ability-to-search-source-code-bb-39

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should probably be community wiki, since it's subjective but ultimately I think of use to the community.

GitHub's greatest strength is that it's widely in use, and also supported by more 3rd parties. For example, continuous integration services like [Travis CI](http://travis-ci.org) or [BuildHive](https://buildhive.cloudbees.com/) feature transparent integration with GitHub.

Personally, I use GitHub for public code because it's pretty widely used and supported and use [Codeplane](http://codeplane.com) for my private code, because $9 a month for unlimited repos is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I don't think that this is a subjective question. I explicitly asked for advantages or reasons to use GitHub and not "which is better?". (I changed the title of the question to reflect that.)

Comment: Ultimately that's still subjective, if there was a concrete answer to "Which is better, service A or service B?", one of the services would have gone out of business.

Comment: That's exactly why I didn't ask for which is better. I though I made that clear... Of course, advantages can be subjective too, but not as subjective as "which is better", since that already includes a weighting of advantages and disadvantages. But anyway...

Comment: Why is subjective a bad thing? Yeah, yeah, I know meta meta meta.